# Python: How to efficiently combine a DataFrame column of collection.counter objects?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, counter

I have a DataFrame with a column of collection.counter objects. I want to combine these counters to one single counter. For a DataFrame with fews rows this works perfectly:

```
counter_sum = Counter()
for _, value in df["Counters"].iteritems():
    counter_sum += value
```

But my DataFrame has hundreds of thousands of rows and the counter objects can be quite large. Is there a more efficient way to combine them?

I have already tried `df["Counters"].sum()`, but pandas does not support this kind of appending.

Comment: pandas is not built to work with these types of objects. You can't vectorize this operation, so you have to loop and manually update the dictionaries. But this doesn't mean you can't make this process more efficient. The big question is: why do you have a `DataFrame` of `Counter` objects in the first place? This doens't seem to make much sense to me. Looks like your problem begins before your starting point in this post

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. In the DataFrame I store, among others, hashtags. The goal is to get a weighted edges list which hashtags are used together often. For each row I get all possible tuples of hashtag combinations and store them in a counter object, one for each row. Last, I want to add up the Counters and get a weighted edges list. Of course I am open to other suggestions.

Comment: Interesting. First thing to notice is that you can avoid having to loop twice through your data points, i.e.you can iterate through your data points while appending to a single `Counter` object. Seconds, this also can be easily parallelized - i.e. divide the operation to run in N clusters, and then you just have to merge N Counters instead of `len(df)` Counters. Looks like a classic [Mapreduce counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce#Examples) problem for example.

Comment: The latter did it! Thanks!